# Do SQL from non-empty table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Suppose you have two tables in MS Access, Table1 and Table2 with the same structure (i.e. the same columns). I would like to write a query where if Table1 is empty then I have to get the data from Table2 else get the data from Table1.

I am not sure how to use IIF statements in such a way.

Comment: If you are saying that the entire table may be empty then just use a simple UNION query to merge both tables.  Access requires you to type the the SQL in for the union query yourself, which would be SELECT * FROM TABLE1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE2;.

Comment: @DHW: The simple version won't work becuz he wants to get values from the second table ONLY WHEN the first one is empty; i.e. the selection between the two tables is mutually exclusive. See my answer which modifies it further to achieve what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. Don't have MS-Access on my machine, but SQL Server accepts it:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, ... FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS TAG, Col1, Col2, ... FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS TAG, Col1, Col2, ... FROM Table2) AS TBL_PARENT
    WHERE TBL_PARENT.TAG = (SELECT MIN(TAG) FROM 
         (SELECT TOP 1 1 AS TAG FROM Table1
         UNION
         SELECT TOP 1 2 AS TAG FROM Table2) AS TBL)
```

**Explanation**

If Table1 is empty, the `SELECT MIN(TAG)` will return 2, otherwise 1. The `WHERE` clause will then filter out all the rows that belong to the desired table. The outer-most `SELECT` is only being used becuz SQL Server doesn't allow using column alias (`TAG` is an alias here) in `WHERE` clause. Thus we have to create a temporary `TBL_PARENT`, so that we could access `TAG` column.

Answer (score 0):

Since you require a somewhat conditional setting and MS Access does not run trigger or transact SQL, consider using VBA in addition to a stored or VBA SQL query.

Of course figure out which form event trigger --OnOpen, OnClick, AfterInsert, AfterUpdate-- to place this in:

```
IF DCount("ID", "Table1") = 0 Then
    'VBA Recordset Query
    db.OpenRecordset Table2sSQLString, dbOpenDynaset
    'Stored SQL Query  
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Table2Query"
Else
    'VBA Recordset Query
    db.OpenRecordset Table2SQLString, dbOpenDynaset
    'Stored SQL Query
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Table1Query"                      
End If
```